# Не отправляются на сервер данные формы через ajax запрос

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, form

Не могу найти в чем проблема.
В учебном проекте добавляю новый функционал. Пользователь на своей странице или странице друга, может создавать посты. Для передачи данных элемента `post` сделал на странице форму и передаю её через `ajax` запрос на сервер.
Вот форма:

```
<form id="post-form">
        <label>Message:
            <input type="text" name="message" required>
        </label>
        <label>Location:
            <input type="text" name="location" required>
        </label>
        <label>Date:
            <input type="text" name="datePosted" required>
        </label>
        <label>UserPosted
            <input type="text" name="userPosted" required>
        </label>
        <label>UserPagePosted
            <input type="text" name="userPagePosted" required>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="button_post">Create post</button>
    </form>
```

Вот `ajax`запрос:

```
$("#post-form").submit(function (e) {
            var form = $(this).serialize();
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/createPost",
                data: form,
                success: function success() {
                    debugger;
                    alert("Created post success.");
                    window.location.href = "profile.html";
                },
                error: function error(xhr) {
                    alert("Failed to exit with: " + xhr + ".");
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Класс `Post`:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "POST")
public class Post extends IdEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String message;
    private String location;
    private Date datePosted;
    private User userPosted;
    private User userPagePosted;
    private List<User> usersTagged;
    //TODO
    //levels permissions

    //TODO
    //comments

    public Post() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "POS_SQ", sequenceName = "POST_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "POS_SQ")
    @Column(name = "POST_ID")
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE", nullable = false)
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @Column(name = "LOCATIONS", nullable = false)
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @Column(name = "DATE_POSTED", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    public Date getDatePosted() {
        return datePosted;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER_POSTED")
    public User getUserPosted() {
        return userPosted;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER_PAGE_POSTED")
    public User getUserPagePosted() {
        return userPagePosted;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "POST_USERS1", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    public List<User> getUsersTagged() {
        return usersTagged;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Post createFromJson(String jsonString){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Post post = null;

        try {
            post = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Post.class);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return post;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Post post = (Post) o;
        return id.equals(post.id) &&
                message.equals(post.message) &&
                location.equals(post.location) &&
                datePosted.equals(post.datePosted) &&
                userPosted.equals(post.userPosted) &&
                userPagePosted.equals(post.userPagePosted);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, message, location, datePosted, userPosted, userPagePosted);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Post.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("message='" + message + "'")
                .add("location='" + location + "'")
                .add("datePosted=" + datePosted)
                .add("userPosted=" + userPosted)
                .add("userPagePosted=" + userPagePosted)
                .toString();
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void setDatePosted(Date datePosted) {
        this.datePosted = datePosted;
    }

    public void setUserPosted(User userPosted) {
        this.userPosted = userPosted;
    }

    public void setUserPagePosted(User userPagePosted) {
        this.userPagePosted = userPagePosted;
    }

    public void setUsersTagged(List<User> usersTagged) {
        this.usersTagged = usersTagged;
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class PostController extends Utils<Post> {

    private PostService postService;
    private PostDAO postDAO;

    @Autowired
    public PostController(PostService postService, PostDAO postDAO) {
        this.postService = postService;
        this.postDAO = postDAO;
    }

    //1. Проверить находится ли юзер делающий пост онлайн
    //2. Проверить статус пользователя на странице которого создается пост
    //3. Если друзья или своя страница, то создаем пост
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/createPost", produces = "text/plain")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addPost(@ModelAttribute Post post, HttpSession session){
        if (post == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("The post is not exist.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        User userPosted = (User) session.getAttribute(String.valueOf(post.getUserPosted().getId()));
        System.out.println("User posted - " + post.getUserPosted());

        try {
            if (userPosted == null){
                return new ResponseEntity<>("The post can not be posted. User is not logged.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            postService.createPost(post);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (BadRequestException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something is wrong with the input.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }catch (InternalServerError e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong...", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/savePost", produces = "text/plain")
    public @ResponseBody
    String save(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException, BadRequestException {
        Post post = mappingObject(req);

        try {
            postService.save(post);
        }catch (BadRequestException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        return "Post saved success.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/updatePost", produces = "text/plain")
    public @ResponseBody
    String update(HttpServletRequest req)throws IOException, BadRequestException {
        Post post = mappingObject(req);
        long inputId = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("postId"));

        try{
            if (postDAO.findById(inputId) == null){
                return "Post with ID - " + inputId + " does not exist in the DB";
            }
            else {
                postService.update(post);
            }
        }catch (BadRequestException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw  e;
        } catch (InternalServerError e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return "Something went wrong...";
        }
        return "User update success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/deletePost", produces = "text/plain")
    public @ResponseBody
    String delete(HttpServletRequest req)throws BadRequestException {
        try {
            Post post = postDAO.findById(Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("postId")));
            long postId = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("postId"));
            if (post == null){
                return "The Post with ID " + postId + " does not exist in the DB.";
            }
            else {
                postService.delete(post.getId());
            }
        } catch (BadRequestException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (InternalServerError e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return "Something went wrong...";
        }
        return "User deleted success";
    }
}
```

Тестирую через `Postman`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дебажу в Идее и вижу, что `post` приходит со значениями всех полей равными `null`
Скрин дебага:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить проблему

Comment: А если вот такой заголовок к запросу добавить? `contentType: "application/json"` И покажите как Post класс выглядит

Comment: ЮрийСПб, добавил класс `Post`. И где добавлять заголовок ?

Comment: ЮрийСПб, поменял `produces = "application/json"` ничего не изменилось, получаю туже ошибку

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `@ModelAttribute` на `@RequestBody` и поставьте в контроллере `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`. Для postman должно сработать.

Comment: Serodv, у меня задача сделать именно через `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: В `postman` поставьте тип тела запроса `x-www-form-urlencoded` вместо `raw` и заполните объект

Comment: Serodv, Вы правы, надо использовать не `@ModelAttribute`, а `@RequestBody`. Оформите ответ, отмечу как решение.

Comment: Serodv, проблема не решилась ... теперь получаю ошибку `HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type` и описание её `The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in a format not
  supported by this method on the target resource.`

Comment: так наверное опять оперяли заголовок contentType: "application/json"

Comment: и наверное все же надо установить consumes="application/json"